# How can I make datetime in multiples of 5 in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, datetime

I have a date

```
time1 = '03-Apr-2004 00:15:00'
aTime = datenum(time1)

time2 = datestr(addtodate(aTime, -53.1*60, 'minute'))
31-Mar-2004 19:09:00
```

But I want time2 to be in the nearest multiple of 5 minutes always. How can I do this (either by adding or multiplying some factor)?

```
Expected answer: 31-Mar-2004 19:10:00
```

Basically, in my entire dataset, I want these values to be always 5,10,15,20,...,55 etc. in the minute section.

Comment: Is `time1` always guaranteed to be a multiple of 5 minutes? If so, all you have to do is change what you are adding to this: `round((-53.1*60)/5)*5`

Comment: @gnovice 95% of the time. But if you have a way to account for if time1 is not a multiple of 5, then that would super aweseome. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have, in fact, is a [`datenum`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html), not [`datetime`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html). You could, for example, first convert it to [`datevec`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datevec.html), then round the minutes, then convert back to `datenum`:

```
>> dv = datevec(time2);
>> dv(5) = round(dv(5) / 5) * 5;
>> datestr(datenum(dv))
ans =
    31-Mar-2004 19:10:00
```

If it is possible that seconds are non-zero, you can also set them to zero:

```
dv(6) = 0;
```